# Check if event is in future - Yup validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I'm currenlty working on yup validation for a page in project. I'm stuck on the following:
User chooses date, timezone and specific time of the event (he can choose times from 00:00 to 23:45 every fifteen minutes). Now, I need to validate if chosen time is in the future. I am really confused: should I first convert current moment to users chosen timezone, or convert user's moment to local timezone, or something else.
Here's what I did first when I was careless about the timezone:

```
[keys.startTime]: yup
      .number()
      .required(errors.required)
      .when(['date'], (date, schema: any) => {
        const currentTimeInMinutes = moment().hours() * 60 + moment().minutes()
        if (
          moment(date).date() === moment().date() &&
          moment(date).month() === moment().month() &&
          moment(date).year() === moment().year()
        )
          return schema.min(currentTimeInMinutes, errors.pastTime)
      }),
```

But then I realised that I didn't take into account chosen timezone.
Start time here represents number of minutes from 00:00 to chosen time, for example if user chooses 00:15, startTime will be 15.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare - the current time (at the point of submission) with the user's selected/entered `date` and `startTime` **both in the user's selected zone**.

```js
// Calculate the offset of the timezone that user selected from UTC
const utcOffset = '+05:30'; // Example of a time zone in India

const currentTime = moment().utcOffset(utcOffset);
const userSelectionTime = 
  moment(date).utcOffset(utcOffset)
    .startOf('day')
    .add(startTime, 'minutes');

/*
 * Check if the difference between the `userSelectionTime` and the `currentTime`
 * is greater than 0 minutes (you can change this as per your requirements)
 */
const selectionIsValid = userSelectionTime.diff(currentTime, 'minutes') > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still struggling because of typescript + yup syntax, but at least now I've got a way to do this.

Comment: Hey, if this resolved your problem, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Also, please post your problem where you're struggling with TS + yup syntax - I can help you there as well.

Comment: Also, I saw something unusual in your code above - in the `.when` block you returned `schema.min(...)` when the if condition was true but you did not return anything for the falsy condition.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to write what happens in other cases. Actually, I thought that I need to validate startTime only if dates are same - and thats why I only included that case. Still, I should have written an else statement with something.
Now, about TS + yup syntax, I have problem with this 
'.when(['date', 'timeZone'], (date, timeZone, schema: any) => {...}'
Seems like I need to provide types of date or timeZone, but I did not suceed.

Comment: Truth be told - it was damn tough (with TS) when using `when` but I found it easier to use `test` for our custom validation use case. Check this out - https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-check-if-data-is-in-future-ts-244k6?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks so much! We also changed to test instead of when in our project.